# Android: Item Text not showing in listView

Tags: java, android, listview

I've been trying for a long time, and I think I have the code in place, but something is wrong because the item is not being added to the listView. Follows my code:

```
public class EditDoctors extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
SimpleAdapter adapter;
List<HashMap<String, String>> painItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
ListView editDoc;
int[] to;
String[] from;
EditText addDoc, docPos;
String row1, row2;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.editdoc);
    addDoc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newDoc);
    docPos = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.docPos);
    editDoc = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.editDoc); 
    TextView textview = new TextView(this);
    textview.setText("This is the Songs tab");
    Button adddocs = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addbutton);
    adddocs.setOnClickListener(this);

    from = new String[] { "row_1", "row_2" };
    to = new int[] { R.id.row1, R.id.row2 };
    adapter = new Adapter(this, painItems, R.layout.mylistlayout,from, to);
    editDoc.setAdapter(adapter);

}
public class Adapter extends SimpleAdapter {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    View row;

    public Adapter(Context context,
            List<? extends Map<String, String>> data, int resource,
            String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);

    }
}

private void addItem() {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("row_1", row1);
    map.put("row_2", row2);
    painItems.add(map);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    row1 = addDoc.getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(this, row1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    row2 = docPos.getText().toString();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    addItem();


}
```

}

This should create a 2-lined listItem, but it doesn't, the lines are empty(no text). The Toast you see in the OnClickMethod returns the text just fine, but the item I add has nothing in it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can see the items if you overrides getView method in adapter class

Answer (score 1):

I was using the Data Binding example from the book *Hello Android* by Ed Burnette (great book).

I changed the item layout from A RelativeLayout to a LinearLayout; however, I did not add an orientation when I made the change.

Once I added **android:orientation="vertical"** everything worked fine.

Two hours of my life on this one.