# Drawers are hidden behing custom view

Tags: java, android, layout

I created a layout. I added a custom view (`pl.jawegiel.endlessblow.view.GameSurface`) and then added two drawers also to the sides (`left_drawer` & `right_drawer`). But when I try to swipe to show either of drawer they are still hidden behind this view and not visible. This is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id = "@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "match_parent">

<FrameLayout
        android:id = "@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "match_parent">


    <pl.jawegiel.endlessblow.view.GameSurface
            android:id = "@+id/gameSurface"
            android:layout_width = "match_parent"
            android:layout_height = "match_parent"/>

    <Spinner
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:id = "@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:background = "@android:color/transparent"
            android:popupBackground = "#33FFFFFF"
            android:visibility = "visible"/>

    <Spinner
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:id = "@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:background = "@android:color/transparent"
            android:popupBackground = "#33FFFFFF"
            android:visibility = "visible"/>

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:id = "@+id/spinner3"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:background = "@android:color/transparent"
        android:popupBackground = "#33FFFFFF"
        android:visibility = "visible"/>

    <Button
            android:text = "chat (0)"
            android:background = "#44C28DDF"
            android:minWidth = "0dp"
            android:minHeight = "20dp"
            android:layout_gravity = "bottom|right"
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content" android:id = "@+id/but2"/>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:orientation = "vertical"
                    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
                    android:layout_height = "@dimen/drawer_height"
                    android:id = "@+id/bottom_drawer"
                    android:background = "#EE116644">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id = "@+id/rvAnimals"
                android:layout_width = "match_parent"
                android:layout_height = "match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop = "true" android:layout_alignParentLeft = "true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart = "true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight = "true" android:layout_alignParentEnd = "true"
                android:layout_above = "@+id/editText7"/>

        <Button
                android:text = "Send"
                android:layout_width = "match_parent"
                android:background = "@color/semiTrans"
                android:layout_height = "wrap_content" android:id = "@+id/but"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true" android:layout_alignParentLeft = "true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart = "true"/>

        <EditText
                android:layout_width = "match_parent"
                android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                android:inputType = "text"
                android:hint = "msg"
                android:ems = "10"
                android:layout_above = "@+id/but" android:layout_alignParentLeft = "true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart = "true" android:id = "@+id/editText7"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>


<ListView android:id = "@+id/left_drawer"
          android:layout_width = "200dp"
          android:layout_height = "match_parent"
          android:layout_gravity = "left"
          android:choiceMode = "singleChoice"
          android:divider = "#080"
          android:dividerHeight = "2dp"
          android:background = "#22FFFFFF"/>

<ListView android:id = "@+id/right_drawer"
          android:layout_width = "200dp"
          android:layout_height = "match_parent"
          android:layout_gravity = "right"
          android:choiceMode = "singleChoice"
          android:divider = "#080"
          android:dividerHeight = "2dp"
          android:background = "#99FFFFFF"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved not by fixing the bug by finding workaround. Namely I have added an ordinary, small TextView on the top of the view and problem seems to be dissapeared, strange thing.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `RelativeLayout` to a `LinearLayout`.

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530940/why-is-my-listview-not-showing-anything/20937881) for more info.

Comment: Yea now drawers seem to show up but on the other hand this custom view `pl.jawegiel.endlessblow.view.GameSurface` does not appear.

Comment: I can' really know why it's happenning, to be honest. Sad not to be able to help you there : (